# Mule PowerShell Connector - The variable '$<variable-name>' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set

Tags: powershell, mule, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

Can't figure out why my variable in my PowerShell script keeps saying the variable is null (**Error: The variable '$' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.**)

Mule Flow = HTTP --> Set Payload --> PowerShell --> Logger --> End

~ MULE XML Code Snippet - Using PowerShell Connector 3.x version ~

```
<powershell:execute config-ref="PowerShell" doc:name="PowerShell" scriptFile="classpath:powershell-script.ps1">
   <powershell:parameters>
     <powershell:parameter key="variable1">#[groovy: payload.variable1 ?: '']</powershell:parameter>
     <powershell:parameter key="variable2">#[groovy: payload.variable2 ?: '']</powershell:parameter>
     <powershell:parameter key="variable3">#[groovy: payload.variable3 ?: '']</powershell:parameter>
   <powershell:parameters>
<powershell:execute>
```

~ PowerShell Code ~

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest 
Param($variable1, $variable2, $variable3)

#Create NEW AD accounts
Function Start-Commands
{
  Write-Output "Start-Commands"
  Write-Output "Parameters-: $variable1 - $variable2 - $variable3"
}

Start-Commands
```

~ Console Output ~

> Root Exception stack trace:
>   org.mule.modules.powershell.PowershellException: The message could not be sent. An exception has been thrown: [{"Exception":"System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: The variable '$flowVarManager' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.\r\n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the issue I removed **Set-StrictMode -Version Latest**

Based off my research I found this article -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode?view=powershell-6

> The Set-StrictMode cmdlet configures strict mode for the current scope and all child scopes, and turns it on and off. When strict mode is on, Windows PowerShell generates a terminating error when the content of an expression, script, or script block violates basic best-practice coding rules.

When Set-StrictMode is ON it is interfering with the passing of the parameter values from the MS PowerShell Connector - Mule 3 to the PS script.  Upon removing the line of code, the parameters were getting set with values.

Comment: That's good to know, but (a) the placement of `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest` in the code in your question is syntactically invalid (`param()` must come _first_), and (b) `Set-StrictMode` doesn't apply to _parameter_ variables (verify with `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest; & { param($foo) $foo }`, which produces _no_ error), so while there must be _some_ code involved that is sensitive to unset variables, it still isn't yours _as shown_. So I'm still curious as to whether the problem is related to Mule at all.

Comment: The problem was not with Mule, it was with the PowerShell script.  If Set-StrictMode does not apply to parameter variables, then how come it was not allowing the parameters to become set?  Then why did removing the Set-StrictMode resolve the issue?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: I can't explain why it worked.  I just removed Set-StrictMode -Version Latest from the PowerShell and everything started working.

Comment: That may be, but the _explanation_ you're giving is incorrect, as mentioned in my previous comment and as discussed in detail in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I understand your response, however Latest was also preventing the params from showing up as well.  The fix was removing that line of code.

Comment: I understand that your fix was _effective_, but saying that `Set-StrictMode` being on interferes with parameter passing is incorrect and misleading. With the sample code you've given, we still don't know what the true cause of the problem is. Using my answer as guidance, I encourage you to dig deeper to find that cause, so we can present it to future readers, including a verdict on whether the problem is specific to MuleConnector or not.

Comment: It will be challenging to dig deeper as the PowerShell connector was something created by MuleSoft.

Comment: Understood, but you can start by investigating where the `$flowVarManager` variable is being referenced.

Answer (score 4):

You've since stated that Mule as the environment from which PowerShell is invoked is *incidental* to the problem.

The symptom - error `The variable '<name>' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.` - indeed implies that a variable is being *accessed* that has never been *set* (initialized), and this kind of error is only raised if `Set-StrictMode -Version 1` or higher is in effect.

- `-Version 1` still allows unset variables inside *expandable strings* (e.g., `"$noSuchVar"`), but `-Version 2` and above does not.
  It's fair to assume that you're not on PowerShell v1 (where `-Version Latest` would imply `-Version 1`), so *any* reference to an unset variable encountered during execution would trigger the error.

However, the *parameter* variables that PowerShell *implicitly* manages (as part of the `param(...)` block) are *not* subject to [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode?view=powershell-6) checking, as the following example demonstrates:

```
PS> Set-StrictMode -Version Latest; & { param($paramVar1) "[$paramVar1]" }
[]
```

<sup>Note: `& { ... }` uses `&`, the call operator, to execute a *script block* `{ ... }`, but such a script block behaves just as a script would.</sup>

As you can see, even though no argument was passed to parameter `-paramVar1` - i.e., no value was bound to the underlying `$paramVar1` *parameter variable* - accessing `$paramVar1` did *not* cause an error, evaluated to `$null`, which in the context of string interpolation becomes the *empty string*.

Contrast this with referencing a truly *unset* variable:

```
PS> Set-StrictMode -Version Latest; & { param($paramVar1) "[$somveVar]" }
The variable '$somveVar' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
```

Because `$someVar` wasn't ever set (and isn't a parameter variable), it triggered the error.

Therefore, we can observe the following about the code printed in the question as of this writing, reproduced here:

```
# NOTE: This code is syntactically invalid due to the placement
#       of the Set-StrictMode call.

Set-StrictMode -Version Latest 
Param($variable1, $variable2, $variable3)

#Create NEW AD accounts
Function Start-Commands
{
  Write-Output "Start-Commands"
  Write-Output "Parameters-: $variable1 - $variable2 - $variable3"
}

Start-Commands
```

- Firstly, the `Set-StrictMode` call cannot be placed *above* the `param(...)` block, as the latter must be the *first* statement in a script.
- Secondly, given that the error message complains about a variable named `$flowVarManager` and given that the code makes no reference whatsoever to that variable, the quoted code *alone* cannot be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I get it at `connect-exchangeonline`, my solution was:

```
$VerbosePreference = $false
```

Cannot update the manifest file because the manifest is not valid. Verify that the manifest file is valid, and then try again.'The
variable `$VerbosePreference` cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.'